# SAS Dates Programmatically

Tags: date, sas

I want to create dates that will automatically be calculated by SAS based on the current date. The dates that I want to calculate are:

The next quarter in the format of YYQ (e.g. 161)
The current year in the format YYYY (e.g. 2015)
The Saturday before the previous Saturday in the format DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 24OCT2015)
The previous Friday in the format DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 30OCT2015)
The first day of the current quarter in the format DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 01OCT2015)
The first day of the current month in the format DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 01OCT2015)
The last day of the current month in the format DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 31OCT2015)

Comment: So what's your question? This is not a coding service, please post what you've tried. A hint is look at the INTNX function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next Quarter

```
qtr = intnx('quarter',date(),1);
format qtr yyqn4.;
```

Current Year

```
year = date();
format year year4.;
```

Saturday before Previous Saturday

```
sat = intnx('week.7',date(),-2);
format sat date9.;
```

Previous Friday

```
fri = intnx('week.6',date(),-1);
format fri date9.;
```

First Day of Current Quarter

```
qstart = intnx('quarter',date(),0);
format qstart date9.;
```

First Day of Current Month

```
mstart = intnx('month',date(),0);
format mstart date9.;
```

Last Day of Current Month

```
mend = intnx('month',date(),0,'end');
format mend date9.;
```

Comment: Your mstart and mend formula's are exactly the same?

Comment: For week intervals, it's often better to use `week.x` (where `x` is the weekday, 1 [Sun] to 7 [Sat]) rather than applying an offset afterwards. 

You can apply the same to other intervals too, e.g. `month.20` is a monthly interval based on the 20th.